# StreamSets can I read runtime value inside some Scripts process like JavaScript process?

Tags: javascript, process, streamsets, step

I try to use JavaScript processor steps in StreamSets.

I defined some environment values and can invoke from expression.

```
${type}='month';
```

In JavaScript, how to use those environment values?

Can you write a js example for get the value of ${type} in JavaScript in StreamSets?

Answer (score 1):

You reference the variable in the same way in JavaScript - EL expression evaluation is performed on the script before it is run. Note that you will need quotes for strings - for example:

```
var myType = '${type}';
```

This also works with the Jython evaluator, but it does NOT work from Groovy due to a clash with the Groovy `${}` syntax.